# Getting Execution timeout for Simple Livewire Chatbot Frontend

Tags: php, laravel, chatbot, laravel-livewire

I am trying to build a chatbot using Laravel and Livewire. I have not included my NLB yet but I seem to be getting stuck when trying to get the Frontend working. I keep be getting stuck between 2 errors. Sometimes I get an execution timeout and sometimes I get an undefined variable error for $messages in my Chatbot.blade.php file.

Here is my Livewire/chatbot.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Chatbot extends Component
{
    public $messages = [];

    public $input;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('chatbot', [
            'messages' => $this->messages,
        ]);
    }

    public function sendMessage()
    {
        // Add user message to the chat
        $this->messages[] = ['sender' => 'user', 'content' => $this->input];
        
        // Process user input and generate chatbot response
        // Add the chatbot response to the chat
        $this->messages[] = ['sender' => 'chatbot', 'content' => $this->generateChatbotResponse($this->input)];

        // Clear the input field
        $this->input = '';
    }

    private function generateChatbotResponse($message)
    {
        // Implement your chatbot logic here
        // Generate an appropriate response based on the user's message
        
        // Return the chatbot response
        return 'Chatbot response';
    }
}
```

I have not included my NLB yet. I am just trying to get the frontend working first

Here is my view/chatbot.blade.php file:

```
@extends('livewire.chatbot')

@section('content')
    <!-- Other page content here -->

    @livewire('chatbot')
@endsection
```

Here is my view/livewire/chabot.blade.php file:

```
<div>
    <div>
        @foreach ($messages as $message)
            <div class="{{ $message['sender'] }}">{{ $message['content'] }}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>

    <form wire:submit.prevent="sendMessage">
        <input type="text" wire:model="input">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The 2 view files were one file previously and I was getting the same error. I have tried changing the render function by changing the view to:

```
 public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.chatbot', [
            'messages' => $this->messages,
        ]);
    }
```

However, when it is the above I get a execution timeout. When I leave it as is I get an undefined varaible error for $messages in this code from the view/livewire/chabot.blade.php file:

```
        @foreach ($messages as $message)
            <div class="{{ $message['sender'] }}">{{ $message['content'] }}</div>
        @endforeach
```

Comment: Your `render()` method does not need to pass anything in, and it does not appear to be rendering the correct view. Should simply be `return view('livewire.chatbot');`

Comment: Also the `<div>` in your `livewire/chatbot.blade.php` should have a `wire:key="chat-{{ $loop->index }}` on it.

Comment: @Qirel, you were correct. I needed to fix my render function but I was also using the views incorrectly. I also needed to fix my main view file by including <livewire: styles/> and <livewire: scripts/>